# Iterating over array in series in mongodb shell

Tags: mongodb, shell, asynchronous

I need to iterate over array inside mongoshell with the aid of async library in the following way:

```
load('/opt/kif/crons/dashboard/node_modules/async/lib/async.js');
async.series([
  function(cb) { print("First"); cb(null,1); },
  function(cb) { print("Second"); cb(null,2); },
  function(cb) { print("Third"); cb(null,3); }
], function(err, res) {
  printjson(res);
});
```

and running

```
mongo testasync.js
```

which returns

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.0
connecting to: test
First
2016-05-01T15:41:45.589+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] ReferenceError: setTimeout is not defined :
_delay<@/opt/kif/crons/dashboard/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:196:9
async.eachOfSeries/iterate/<@/opt/kif/crons/dashboard/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:272:29
only_once/<@/opt/kif/crons/dashboard/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:13
_parallel/</<@/opt/kif/crons/dashboard/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:723:17
_restParam/<@/opt/kif/crons/dashboard/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:167:1
@testasync.js:3:33
_parallel/<@/opt/kif/crons/dashboard/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:718:1
iterate@/opt/kif/crons/dashboard/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:262:1
async.eachOfSeries@/opt/kif/crons/dashboard/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:281:9
_parallel@/opt/kif/crons/dashboard/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:717:1
async.series@/opt/kif/crons/dashboard/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:739:9
@testasync.js:2:1

failed to load: testasync.js
[root@NQPC002 dashboard]#
```

How do I do that?

Comment: The MongoDB shell is generally synchronous; what async operations are you performing where you need this?

Comment: I have an array of object Ids and I want to update each of them one after another in such a fashion: for (var i=0;i<arr.length;i++) { db.dash.update({_id: arr[i].id}, {$inc: {prizes: arr[i].prize}}); } Is that operation synchronous?

Comment: Yep, the update methods in the shell are synchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the MongoDB shell uses JavaScript, its database access methods are all synchronous so a sequence of calls is already performed serially.

So a method like [`db.collection.update`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db.collection.update) directly returns a [`WriteResult`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#writeresults-update) instead of using a callback.